# Nothing can go in between custom tags - <myTag_vue> ... </> in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, idioms

The structure of my vue app is this:

root.vue:

```
<template>

<header-yo> <h1> visible? or not? </h1> </header-yo> //content btw tags is invisible
<footer> </footer>

</template>

<script>
import Footer from "./components/footer";
import Header from "./components/header";

export default {
  components: {
    "footer": Footer,
    "header-yo": Header  // header-yo is "custom tag" now!
  }
};
</script>

<style> ...</style>
```

header:

```
<template>
 <h1>rrrrr</h1> //this is visible

</template>

<script> </script>

<style scoped>  </style>
```

When we create this custom tag "" - **it only serves as declarator of a component?**

Nothing can be added in btw custom tags?
Because I can only see on the webpage what's inside my actual header.vue file, not inside my own custom  tags. Is this the vue-idiomatic style?
the root.vue that has all other components is only there to put things together, and nothing can go in btw custom tags - they only show what components\other vue files are there? If I want to add something in header- it should go in corresponding separate header.vue file?

The js fiddle is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/24695vvr0r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your trying to do is comparable to AngularJS transclusion mechanism. You need to actually tell vuejs where the content will be inserted in the template by using a `<slot></slot>` element:

```
<template>
  <h1>rrrrr</h1> // this is visible
  <slot></slot>  // this is where "<h1> visible? or not? </h1>" would be inserted
</template>
```

You can find more about this in [vuejs component guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots) or the [dedicated Slot documentation page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html).